# Spotify is not working at all after cancelling premium

Tags: spotify

Everytime I double-click a song in my library (saved, not local) I get an error that the current song cannot be played. I cancelled premium and I've played a few songs in my app, but the desktop software and web player will not play anything. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have "high quality streaming" still selected. Turning off the option should fix it.

This is a premium feature, but premium features are not automatically disabled, so you may see such errors when trying to play from your library.